# Windows user environment variables not available in OpenSSH session

Tags: ssh, environment-variables

I am running OpenSSH server on my Windows XP machine. When I log in from a remote machine using PuTTY or any other ssh client, I am unable to see any of my user-level environment variables from the shell session. I see only the global ones.

Do I need to modify any settings for the remote session to gain access to all the windows environment variables?

Comment: For now, I'm going to move some of the user variables to global scope, but I'm still looking for a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the OpenSSH service is running as the LOCAL SYSTEM or NETWORK accounts. Find the service in the Services control panel (Start -> Run: services.msc) and right-click + choose Properties. On the Log On tab, change the service to run under your account.

Warning: This may cause all SSH sessions to use your account in authenticating. This may not actually be a good thing, but if you are the only user it probably doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I tried it, but the service is failing to start after I ask it to logon with my domain account. This is the error that I see:

"Could not start the OpenSSH Server service on Local Computer.
Error 1067: The process terminated unexpectedly."